# Batch compare 2 folders with .CSV output

Tags: csv, batch-file, compare, export

I´m new to batch. I´m trying to compare the content from 2 different folders and output the result in a .csv. The comparison is well done. However, when I try to export the result to 2 different .csv (so that I can merge them later), the .csv files are empty, even if they shouldn´t.

````
SET PATH1=C:\Users\ujurado\Desktop\Comp1
SET PATH2=C:\Users\ujurado\Desktop\Comp2

echo %PATH1%
echo %PATH2%

robocopy %PATH1% %PATH2% /L /NJH /NJS /NP /NS
robocopy %PATH2% %PATH1% /L /NJH /NJS /NP /NS

(for %%i in ("%PATH2%\*") do if exist "%PATH1%\%%~nxi" (ECHO(already exists: "%PATH1%\%%~nxi") ELSE ECHO(NOT found "%PATH1%\%%~nxi")>comparaPrimeroConSegundo.csv
(for %%i in ("%PATH1%\*") do if exist "%PATH2%\%%~nxi" (ECHO(already exists: "%PATH2%\%%~nxi") ELSE ECHO(NOT found "%PATH2%\%%~nxi")>comparaSegundoConPrimero.csv

copy comparaPrimeroConSegundo.csv+comparaSegundoConPrimero.csv comparaFinal.csv```
````

Comment: Aside from your reported issue. why don't you just output to one file to begin with? i.e. remove `)>comparaPrimeroConSegundo.csv` from your first `for` command line; then remove the leading `(`, and change `>comparaSegundoConPrimero.csv` to `"comparaFinal.csv"` on your second `for` command line.

Answer (score 0):

Just an untested idea, but why not try a single robocopy command *(**Note:** delimiters are a single <kbd>TAB</kbd> character)*:

```sh
@Set "PATH1=%UserProfile%\Desktop\Comp1"
@Set "PATH2=%UserProfile%\Desktop\Comp2"
@(For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=  " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%PATH1%" "%PATH2%" /L /NDL /NJH /NJS /NP /NS /XC /XN /XO') Do @Echo %%G) 1>"comparaFinal.csv"
```

Comment: Just to add, that this should list the files which are unique to each directory, which is my assumption of the intent. I say that because there's no need to concatenate the list all of the files in `Comp1` which exist in `Comp2`, and all of those in `Comp2` which exist in `Comp1`, because both those lists would be the same.